# Gradle sync failed: Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KotlinSourceSetProviderImplKt

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

```
21:10   Gradle sync failed: Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KotlinSourceSetProviderImplKt
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (7s 78ms)
```

hi guys, i've tried to invalidate cache and restart,sync project with gradle and file system,update latest stable kotlin, create new project and let the android studio download all update and still got this same error. can anyone help me ? sorry im really new in android stuff

this is my= app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.asusx.rogmode.rog"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Wed Jun 10 20:24:06 ICT 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: can you share the IDE logs, as mentioned in the error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into the same problem when I updated my Android Studio from 3.5 to 4.0.

I changed ext.kotlin_version to 1.3.72 and then ran a build. That fixed the problem.

This link gave me the hint: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html